# Push UIViewController without link to the previous one on the UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have UINavigationController and UIViewController, then I push another viewcontroller, but I don't need link to the previous one on the NavigationBar. What's the right way do to such thing?

Thank you!

Comment: you did not want to pop back to root view controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the property of UINavigationBar

```
@property(nonatomic,assign) BOOL hidesBackButton; // If YES, this navigation item will hide the back button when it's on top of the stack.
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do with the controller after you display it.  If it's going to be dismissed some other way, you can make it modal instead of pushing it.  If it's going to be the new first item in your navigation stack, you can replace the existing controller.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! How can I replace it without damaging the tree of views? I tried to use     [code]self.navigationController setViewControllers:arrayWithOneTargetController[/code], but it didn't help and I received an exception that tree was damaged.